# I cannot find the name of a dynamically created javascript object (in jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page which uses javascript to add some textboxes to the page, and then we try to do some work based on these later.

What I am having a lot of trouble with though is that I cannot return the 'name' value which I am saving with the js.

Full page source (albeit a simplified version) is below.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //we use live because the inputs havent been created yet. 
        $('.myclass').live('blur', function () {

            //debugger;
            alert('textbox selected has ID '+ $(this).attr('id') ); //this returns txtInput
            alert('textbox selected has name '+ $(this).attr('name') ); //this returns null (or an empty string). 
        });

    AddInputTextBox("My Label: ", "txtInput", "mydiv", "MyName");

    });

    function AddInputTextBox(LabelValue, Id, divToAddTo, NameKey) {
        //debugger;
        var txtbox = document.createElement('input');
        txtbox.setAttribute("type", "text");
        txtbox.setAttribute("id", Id);
        txtbox.setAttribute("name", NameKey);
        txtbox.setAttribute("class", "myclass"); 

        alert('Textbox created with name = ' + txtbox.name);

        var foo = document.getElementById(divToAddTo);
        foo.innerHTML += LabelValue;
        foo.appendChild(txtbox);
    } 
    </script> 
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mydiv">
        <!-- placeholder -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So as you can see, document.ready runs and creates one textbox.
when the blur fires (box loses focus) - I can access the ID, class, type, etc, but I cannot get a value for the 'name'.

Sure it is something dead simple, but can someone tell me why?

Comment: It works for me here: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/K88fL/ which browser is giving you issues?

Comment: Did you leave out the part where you loaded jQuery?

Comment: works for me as well: http://www.jsfiddle.net/subhaze/hh8aK/

Comment: works fine for me in FF, IE, Opera, Chrome, Safari ..

Comment: Hmmm, I have just tried in FF and it works (never thought of it being a browser issue), but IE does not work. IE8 to be precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `<input>` elements with IE, you have to do it like this:

```
var txtbox = document.createElement('<input name="' + NameKey + '">');
```

IE doesn't like you changing the "name" attribute of an `<input>` once it exists, so you have to tell it what you're going to do in the call to "createElement()".

One might wonder why you're not using jQuery to build your dynamic content, since you've loading it anyway.

(*edit* I thought it was the "type" attribute, but now I think it's "name".)

Comment: the javascript is an old method which is well-tested and reliable. i'm just modernizing the page as a whole. and if it aint broke dont fix it.   Thanks for the answer though, exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/dem5d/

Am I missing something?

Bob